# SQL Join query with OR Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Need help in creating a SQL query. Little confused so asking question. Here is the situation:

I have one table say EmpInfo:
`EmpFirstName, EmpLastName, EmpID, EmpGender, EmpDOB, EmpAddress`
Table2 EmpMasterID:
`EmpID1, EmpId2, AbsoluteEmpID`

EmpInfo contains sample data:

```
EmpFirstName | EmpLastName | EmpID | EmpGender | EmpDOB  | EmpAddress
First1       | Last1       | 10    |  M        | 1/1/92  | Addr1
First2       | Last2       | 20    |  F        | 1/12/92 | Addr2
First3       | Last3       | 30    |  F        | 1/12/94 | Addr3
First4       | Last4       | 40    |  M        | 1/2/94  | Addr4
First5       | Last5       | 60    |  M        | 1/1/91  | Addr5
First6       | Last6       | 70    |  F        | 1/12/92 | Addr6
First7       | Last7       | 80    |  F        | 1/12/95 | Addr7
First8       | Last8       | 90    |  M        | 1/2/97  | Addr8
```

EmpMasterID sample data:

```
EmpID1 | EmpId2 | AbsoluteEmpID
10     |  20    |  10
60     |  70    |  60
```

Now I have to join these 2 tables and get the following columns:

`EmpID, EmpFirstName, EmpLastName, AbsoluteEmpID`

The value of AbsoluteEmpID will be picked up from the EmpMasterID table if `EmpInfo.EmpID = EmpMasterID.EmpID1 OR EmpInfo.EmpID = EmpMasterID.EmpID2`
Otherwise the value of AbsoluteEmpID will be EmpID itself.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: YOu mean if EmpInfo.EmpID = EmpMasterID.EmpID1 OR EmpInfo.EmpID = EmpMasterID.EmpID2 ?

Comment: Correct-- that was a typo... Thanks for asking

Comment: What do you want to get if EmpInfo.EmpID matches EmpMasterID.EmpID1 on one row and matches EmpMasterID.EmpID2 on a different row, and the AbsoluteEmpID values are different on those two rows?

Comment: What results do you want?  To me, the question looks like a simple join on `AbsoluteEmpId`.

Comment: @rd_nielsen Good question. I don't think people even understood what are you trying to ask.

Answer (score 5):

This will join either on `EmpID1` or on `EmpID2`. If both fails, `left join` ensures you get a row with `null` and then you just replace `null` with `empid`:

```
select ei.EmpID, 
       ei.EmpFirstName, 
       ei.EmpLastName, 
       isnull(em.AbsoluteEmpID, ei.EmpID) as AbsoluteEmpID
from EmpInfo ei
left join EmpMasterID em on ei.empid = em.EmpID1 or ei.empid = em.EmpID2
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be based on an inner join

```
update EmpInfo 
INNER JOIN EmpMasterID On (EmpInfo.EmpID = EmpMasterID.EmpID1 
                           OR EmpInfo.EmpID = EmpMasterID.EmpID2)
SET EmpID = AbsoluteEmpID
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just want this?

```
SELECT ei.EmpID, ei.EmpFirstName, ei.EmpLastName, em.AbsoluteEmpID
FROM EmpMasterID em JOIN
     EmpInfo ei
     ON ei.EmpID = ei.AbsoluteEmpID;
```

I don't see what `OR` has to do with this query.