# SQL Where clause compare multiple columns against another tables singular column

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

1st table has columns:

```
Id, object, object_piece1, object_piece2, object_piece3
```

1. table   wood           leg             bolt
2. lamp    stand          bolt            lightbulb
3. door    wood           bolt

2nd table has columns:

```
id, piece_name
```

1. bolt
2. wood
3. leg
4. lightbulb

I am trying to use the 2nd table as a list of pieces I have and the 1st table as what i can make.

But my SQL clause is not functioning like I would expect:

I have

```
SELECT 
    [DBOne].object, [DBOne].object_piece1, [DBOne].object_piece2, 
    [DBOne].object_piece3
FROM 
    DBOne, DBTwo
WHERE
    [DBOne].object_piece1 = [DBTwo].piece_name
    AND [DBOne].object_piece2 = [DBTwo].piece_name
    AND [DBOne].object_piece3 = [DBTwo].piece_name;
```

When I run it, I get no records back. Can you help point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Replace `and` with `or`, it should execute

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s i agree with you, bad method of joinign tables

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40706849/sql-join-query-with-or-clause

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is non-standard SQL). Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...